# WPF How to use my Resource Dictionary containing a data template within my main XAML page

Tags: wpf, dictionary, mvvm, resources

My Resource Dictionary, which contains a data template I wish to use for each VM associated with it.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:IntSimulator.ViewModels.EquipmentVMs"
                xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:IntSimulator.Converters"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IntSimulator.ResourceDictionary">


<converters:ScaleXCoordConverter x:Key="ScaleXCoordConverter"></converters:ScaleXCoordConverter>
<converters:ScaleYCoordConverter x:Key="ScaleYCoordConverter"></converters:ScaleYCoordConverter>

<DataTemplate x:Key="KeyMcKeyface" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CircuitTrackViewModel}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineCoords}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <!--When we click on the line, it will increase Z-index and change colour, to bring occupied track forward and highlight -->
                <Line
                                            X1="{Binding X1, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}}" Y1="{Binding Y1, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter}}"
                                            X2="{Binding X2, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}}" Y2="{Binding Y2, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter}}"
                                            Stroke="{Binding DataContext.Colour.Colour, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2}}" 
                                            StrokeThickness="1" StrokeEndLineCap="{Binding EndLineCap}" StrokeStartLineCap="{Binding StartLineCap}">
                    <Line.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.OccupyTrackCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2}}" CommandParameter="True"/>
                    </Line.InputBindings>

                    <Line.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding DataContext.DisplayViewModel.MainOffsetX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}}" 
                                                        Y="{Binding DataContext.DisplayViewModel.MainOffsetY, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
                    </Line.RenderTransform>

                </Line>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've added

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>


            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="CircuitTracksResourceDictionary" Source="ResourceDictionary/CircuitTracksResourceDictionary.xaml"/>


    </ResourceDictionary>
```

To my App.xaml. I now wish to use this resource dictionary in my main xaml page, but unsure of how to do this.

I used to use user controls to do this, like this:

```
   //OLD CODE
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CircuitTrackViewModel}">
                    <userControlLines:CircuitTrackUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"></userControlLines:CircuitTrackUserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
```

But this was causing performance issues. Ideally I'd just like to place the data template within my main xaml page like this but using my resource dictionary as a static resource. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which resource are you trying to use?

Comment: The CircuitTracksResourceDictionary. Apologies, I forgot I left that in there as a style. I'll edit my question to remove it. @mm8

Comment: That's a `ResourceDictionary` that contains several resources. Which particular resource are you trying to use in your `UserControl`?

Comment: I'm trying to grab the DataTemplate from the ResourceDictionary and use that @mm8

Comment: So why are you defining a new `DataTemplate` in the `UC`?

Comment: I'm not, I was just showing how I used to do it, to show functionality wise how I want it to be. Sorry for any confusion. @mm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `x:Key` from your `DataTemplate` to make it implicit:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CircuitTrackViewModel}">
```

Then you just have to merge the `ResourceDictionary` into your `App.xaml` to apply it to all `CircuitTrackViewModel` objects throughout your application:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```